# Fire one trigger when modifying two different tables

Tags: oracle, triggers

We have a problem with our DBMS (Oracle) which prevents us from using materialized views, so my boss came with this idea of implementing it using a real table and triggers; inserting, updating or deleting from this table when an insert, update, or delete is done in one of the tables upon which the materialized view would had been based.

I know I'm going to hell for agreeing to this, but the time for lamentations is well overdue.

My problem is, I don't know how to make this trigger to fire when a change is done in any of these tables, and not in only one of them. Something like this doesn't seem to work:

```
create trigger my_trigger
after insert or update or delete on table1, table2
```

Also, would there be a way to create just one trigger instead of one for insert, one for update, and one for delete?

Comment: One trigger is always for exactly one table. You can't have one trigger for two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER test
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON tabletest
  REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW 
  FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE
      << Your declarations>>
BEGIN


IF INSERTING THEN 
<<Your insertions>>
END IF;

IF UPDATING THEN 
<<Your updations>>
END IF;    

IF DELETING THEN 
<<Your deletions>>
END IF;


EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    <<exception handling>>;

END;
```

Also you cannot have multiple tables in the same trigger, you need to write the same code and change the table name in each trigger if the functionality is the same.